# Filtering out class from high resolution map in lower resolution map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, resolution, aggregation

I have a soil sealing fraction map (SSF) with a resolution of 30 meters and a high resolution land cover map (HRLC) with a resolution of 5 meters. 
I would like to use the HRLC map to filter some classes out of my SSF.

What is the best way of aggregating the land cover map to a lower resolution in order to do this ?

Or is it better that I resample my SSF to 5 meter resolution, filter out the classes, and aggregate the map to 30 meters again ?

**EDIT** : I want to filter out roads by this technique. So my second option won't work without corrupting the pixels next to roads.

Comment: What version of ArcGIS Desktop are you using?

Comment: I am using arcgis 10.4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have asked around and found the answer.

The first question to be asked is whether the objects of the class to be filtered out match the resolution of the SSF maps. In this case, the objects (the roads) are often smaller than the 30 meters resolution.

To do this, it is necessary to re-sample the low resolution SSF maps to the same resolution as the high resolution maps using the re-sample tool.

Then it is possible to use the high resolution map to filter out the desired class. In this case, by making a binary mask assigning 0 to the class to be filtered out and 1 to the rest of the image and to use Raster Calculator to multiply the LC map with the SSF map. 
It's then necessary to pursue the rest of the analysis with the new resolution SSF maps (which are then much larger).

An alternative for this, is to resample both maps to a resolution somewhere in between that matches the resolution of the objects in the class that has to be filtered out.

To aggregate the land cover map it's best to use a majority filter.